# Xcode 8: send email from simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, email, simulator

I have to test the send of emails from my swift application. Because actually I don't have a real device, I want to know if the email app is added to the simulator of this last version of Xcode (Xcode 8). I searched but I didn't find any information about this. What I have found is that it's impossible to send email from simulator because there is no email app and configuration on it. This information concerne the other versions of Xcode. So what about this new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to open MFMailComposer with iOS simulator, but when you open it it will crash (Mail Composer), so it is not possible for you to check whether the mail is sending or not with iOS Simulator.